# How to add item to ArrayList by Thread in Java

Tags: java, arraylist

I want to generate customer object and store them in ArrayList, but I could not.

Here is my Customer class

```
public class Customer {
private int customerID;
private int processTime;

ArrayList<Integer> customerIDList = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<Integer> processTimeList = new ArrayList<>();

public int getCustomerID() {
    return customerID;
}

public void setCustomerID(int customerID) {
    this.customerID = customerID;
}

public int getProcessTime() {
    return processTime;
}

public void setProcessTime(int processTime) {
    this.processTime = processTime;
}

public ArrayList<Integer> getCustomerIDList() {
    return customerIDList;
}

public void setCustomerIDList(ArrayList<Integer> customerIDList) {
    this.customerIDList = customerIDList;
}

public ArrayList<Integer> getProcessTimeList() {
    return processTimeList;
}

public void setProcessTimeList(ArrayList<Integer> processTimeList) {
    this.processTimeList = processTimeList;
} 
}
```

CustomerThread class which is generate customer object 10 times and between two customers 100 msec

```
public class CustomerThread extends Thread {
Customer c = new Customer();
Methods method = new Methods();

@Override
public void run() {

    for(int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
        try {
            //c.setCustomerID(i); 
            //c.setProcessTime(method.generateProcessTime());

            c.getCustomerIDList().add(i);
            c.getProcessTimeList().add(method.generateProcessTime());

            System.out.println("ID  : " + c.getCustomerIDList().get(i) + " - Process Time : " + c.getProcessTimeList().get(i));
            Thread.sleep(100);   
        }
        catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(CustomerThread.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }   
} 
}
```

Method of generateProcessTime is generate random int numbers, there is no problem.
Here is my Test class

```
public class Test {
public static void main(String[] args) {

    CustomerThread ct = new CustomerThread();

    ct.start();

}
}
```

When I execute these, this error will happen,

> Exception in thread "Thread-0" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 1, Size: 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're adding numbers `1..10` into the list

```
c.getCustomerIDList().add(i);
```

But then you're trying to retrieve numbers at indexes `1..10`

```
c.getCustomerIDList().get(i)
```

But lists are indexed from `0`, that's why you get `IndexOutOfBoundsException`
You should rather iterate from `0..9` and add value `i + 1`:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  ...
  c.getCustomerIDList().add(i + 1);
  ...
```